# Java synchronized

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

В  книге Шилдта - "Java 8 Полное руководство" написано, что вместо deprecated методов suspend(),  resume ()  или  stop () для управления состоянием потока нужно использовать костыльчики на основе методов wait() и notify() в синхронизированном контексте. 
Дается вот такой вот пример класса:

```
   public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
        Thread.sleep(200);
       synchronized(this) {
          while(suspendFlag == true) {
            wait(); 
        }
       }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
  }

  synchronized void mysuspend() {
    suspendFlag = true;
  }

  synchronized void myresume() {
    suspendFlag = false;
    notify();
  }
```

**Внимание вопрос:**
После того как я вызову mysuspend(), обьекта этого класса suspendFlag станет true и начнет работать вот это:

```
synchronized(this) {
          while(suspendFlag == true) {
            wait(); 
        }}
```

"это" будет постоянно занимать монитор объекта, так почему же тогда у меня остается возможность вызвать синхронизированный метод **myresume()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызов `wait()` освобождает монитор и появляется возможность вызывать другие методы.

[Из документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--):

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases
>   ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies
>   threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a
>   call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then
>   waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes
>   execution.